Long Execution Time for Supabase Update Call in Next.js Application
I'm working on a Next.js application that uses Supabase as the backend database. I'm encountering a performance issue where an update operation on the database takes significantly longer when executed through the Next.js app compared to running the equivalent SQL query directly in the database. Sample:
await client
  .from(TABLE)
  .update({ test: updatedTest })
  .match({ id })
  .throwOnError();

Next.js Version: ^14.2.3
Supabase: 1.50.4
Supabase/supabase-js: ^2.20.0

Why is there such a significant difference in execution time between the direct SQL query and the Supabase client call in the Next.js application?
Any ideas why the significant difference in execution time?
